# In Visual studio Code,how to debug (using breakpoint ) Protractor test scripts using javascript along with Jasmine framework?

Tags: javascript, debugging, protractor, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug **protractor** test using **javascript** along with Jasmine framework in **Visual studio Code(vscode)**. However, whenever I run my test cases by a**dding breakpoints**, as soon as the script halts at breakpoint, the actions are not reflected( e.g, filling the text field, click button, etc.) on chrome browser.

Once we continue the debugging(play button) then the all actions are reflected on browser. In short, **browser and code doesn't debug Synchronously when applied breakpoint.**

I read many posts but it is not working for my issue.

Please give me solution in order to resolve issue.

Thanks.

launch.json:

```
 {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/conf.js"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outFiles": [],
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outFiles": []
        }
    ]
}
```